# Can eclipse pydev interpret a file as a python file without a suffix

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

If I have a python file that has no suffix.  Can pydev read that file as a python file using the first line of the file if it includes a #!/usr/bin/python?  I'm not really concerned specifically about using that first line, just that that line exists and might be useable.  If there is a manual way to mark a file as a python file without mucking with its suffix that'd be fine as well.

Comment: Why not try opening it in and see what happens?

Comment: @David I'm not sure what you are saying, when I open the file it is not treated as a python file, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Ah, okay. You might want to include what you tried in your question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just right-click on the file, then hit "Open With" -> "Other", then choose "Python editor" and hit OK. Eclipse will remember your choice and from then on will open that particular file in the Python editor when you double-click it.